# How do we send emails to specific running threads using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have used if controller using ${___threadNum} function but it's not working.
Few times working fine and sometimes not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot help without seeing your [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) setup, make sure to use the correct expression, i.e. [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) there

For example this is how you can send emails only by thread # 2:

[image]

Textual representation of the function just in case:

```
${__jexl3(${__threadNum} == 2,)}
```

And demo:

[image]

As you can see only 2nd thread is sending the email.

Also try [increasing JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) to DEBUG level, it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter" level="debug" />
```

Once you apply the change and restart JMeter you will be able to see the complete information regarding what's going under the hood when you execute your test, it will help you to compare the "working" and "not working" cases and figure out the reason.